# How to write a generic entity getter method including all the navigation properties?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I wrote a generic repo method including all the navigation properties as following:

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAllWhereAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression, bool include = false)
    {
        if (include)
            foreach (var name in _db.Model.FindEntityType(typeof(T)).GetNavigations().Select(e => e.Name))
                _db.Set<T>().Include(name).Load();

        return await _db.Set<T>().AsNoTracking().Where(expression).ToListAsync();
    }
```

However, when I call this method, my resulting entities don't have their navigation property included. What should I do?

Comment: `Include()` calls need to be chained together and the same `IQueryable<T>` used in the `return`. LINQ in general is immutable and returns new query objects even from things which appear to modify the query.

Answer (score 1):

See if this modification compiles, I am no where near a compiler right now so can't be sure.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAllWhereAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression, bool include = false)
{
    var query = _db.Set<T>();
    if (include)
        foreach (var name in _db.Model.FindEntityType(typeof(T)).GetNavigations().Select(e => e.Name))
            query = query.Include(name);

    return await query.AsNoTracking().Where(expression).ToListAsync();
}
```

Comment: query is actually a DbSet here so I get Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<T>' to 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbSet<T>' **Edit:** var query = _db.Set<T>().AsQueryable(); works. Thanks.